# How can i add a preload function for my images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw this solution and i don't understand where is the preload here:

```
function preloadImage(url)
{
    var img=new Image();
    img.src=url;
}
```

On my html file i have this part:

```
<div id="slideShow">



    <img src="Images/radar000025.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000203.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000251.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000267.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000283.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000284.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000301.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000539.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000556.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000571.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000588.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000589.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000794.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000810.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000811.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000812.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000813.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000814.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000830.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000831.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000832.Gif" alt="slide" />
    <img src="Images/radar000833.Gif" alt="slide" />            



    <!-- #slideShow --></div>
```

Then in the bottom i'm calling javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="SlideShow.js"></script>
```

In the SlideShow.js i have the functions of timer and buttons and events.
And last i have a style file Screen.css for all the styling.

What i want to do is to make a preloader for all the images maybe even with a progressBar that show each image loading progress.

I saw some examples and i saw this answer above of the small function but i'm not sure how to use it with my code.

This is my site with the working slideshow but without a preloader:

[Slide Show](http://newsxpressmedia.com/SlideShow.php)

And this is the SlideShow javascript file and css file: newsxpressmedia.com/SlideShow.js , newsxpressmedia.com/Screen.css

Maybe using ajax for the preloading is better not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this might help you . Try this

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* Preloader */
#preloader {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 background-color:#fff; /* change if the mask should have another color then white */
 z-index:99; /* makes sure it stays on top */
}

#status {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 position:absolute;
 left:50%; /* centers the loading animation horizontally one the screen */
 top:50%; /* centers the loading animation vertically one the screen */
 background-image:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-IdPZAIYB_38/UAsThCuCjcI/AAAAAAAABK0/wzErRGy13NU/s1600/loading.gif); /* path to your loading animation */
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 margin:-100px 0 0 -100px; /* is width and height divided by two */
}
```

```html
<body>
  
<!-- Preloader -->
<div id="preloader">
 <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

    
  
  
<!-- Your Website Content -->
<div>
    This is your website content
    
<img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar002407.Gif" />

</div>
  
  
  

<!-- jQuery Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
    
<!-- Preloader -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
  $(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
   $("#status").fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
   $("#preloader").delay(350).fadeOut("slow"); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
  })
 //]]>
</script> 
  
</body>
```

Comment: Sarath It's working but how do i preload or loading all the images in the server directory ? In your code you are using one gif. But i have there many gifs files. I want to preload all the images first then in the end to run the slideshow. I added my code to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2vcLyvr4/ and when i make run i see the animation and then the first image displayed.

Comment: Sarath i forgot also to mention that the whole SlideShow.cs thats the javascript code is not working at all now. I mean no buttons and timer. I wanted them to show displayo nce all images loaded.

Comment: Dear Haim , Please check out this http://jsfiddle.net/69pLhrkm/. I didn't get your exact problem but i think you are trying to preload all images before loading the page. I have done it in this example. I've added just 3 images. add your required images in the script.  I have included necessary comments where you have to make changes in your code.

Comment: Sarath i didn't look at the full code yet i saw it's working great i will look at the code it self now. I just wanted to ask the perloading load first only the first image or it's preloading first all the images ?

Comment: it will preload all the images given in the array before loading. Did you notice the array which specifies the images to be loaded?

Comment: Sarath yes the variable imgList right ? I asked that since it's pre loading all the images very fast so i was just wondering, it's great.

Comment: Haim, Look at line number 142 onwards. There you have to specify the images to be loaded. Also the very quick loading may be because of your browser has all the images cached. Load again after clear your browser cache , it might take a while to preload..